# How can I remove the key from an array but keeping the value in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
language: 
 [
   {added: "English"}
 ]
```

What I want to do is to remove the key `added` but I want to keep the value `English` in the same array.

The result I except:

```
language: 
 [
  "English"
 ]
```

By far I have tried something like this:

```
for(let i  in language) {
 delete language[i].added
}
console.log(language)
```

This will remove the key and the value as well.
How can I remove the key, but keep the value in the same array?

Comment: Consider looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?

Answer (score 2):

If the objects just consist of a single property, `added`, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the objects into scalar values:

```js
data = {
  language: [
    { added: "English" }
  ]
}

data.language = data.language.map(o => o.added)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't deleting a key, you're replacing an entry in an array. The old entry is an object with a single key and the new one is it's value:

```js
 language = [
   {added: "English"}
 ]
 
for (let i in language) {
  language[i] = Object.values(language[i])[0]
}
 
 console.log(language);
```